# Python pickle.load does not execute my Class __new__ method

Tags: python, pickle

I develop a Class that need to manage memory in its `__new__` method. 
It works well when I instantiate an object.
But `__new__` is NOT executed when using pickle.load

```
   >>>import pickle 

   >>>class Foo(object):
    ...    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
    ...        print('Foo:__new__')
    ...        print('args: [{}]'.format(args))
    ...        print('kwds: [{}]'.format(kwds))
    ...        return cls

    >>>foo = Foo()
    Foo:__new__
    args: [()]
    kwds: [{}]

    >>>fp=open('test.bin', 'wb')
    >>>pickle.dump(foo,fp)
    >>>fp.close()
    >>>fp=open('test.bin', 'rb')
    >>>foo = pickle.load(fp)
```

! My problem is here: the method Foo::**new** is not executed

```
    >>>foo
    __main__.Foo
```

Comment: This is just an example class not the class that needs to manage its memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**new** method is not correct.

Replace with the following one, resolve my issue.

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
    print('Foo:__new__')
    print('args: [{}]'.format(args))
    print('kwds: [{}]'.format(kwds))
    return object.__new__(cls)
```